# Supported API test fails (C++/CX)

Tags: c++, windows-store-apps

I wrote an application (C++/CX) that targets Windows 8.1 and today I wanted to check it with WACK 3.4 tool (for the first time). The report said that "Supported API test" had failed. I'm pretty sure I don't use any 'illigal' API. I don't use 3rd party libraries either. I tried all solutions I've googled but non of them worked.

My next step was to create brand new C++/CX project that targets Windows 8.1 and try to validate it. When I did it, I've bumped into the very same issue.

Here is the report (it's in polish but it baiscly says that given API is not supported by this type of application). I have the same errors for both applications.

```
◦Interfejs API ??0ChangedStateException@Platform@@Q$AAA@XZ w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ??0Delegate@Platform@@Q$AAA@XZ w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ??0DisconnectedException@Platform@@Q$AAA@XZ w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ??0FailureException@Platform@@Q$AAA@P$AAVString@1@@Z w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ??0FailureException@Platform@@Q$AAA@XZ w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ??0InvalidArgumentException@Platform@@Q$AAA@P$AAVString@1@@Z w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ??0NotImplementedException@Platform@@Q$AAA@XZ w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ??0NullReferenceException@Platform@@Q$AAA@XZ w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ??0Object@Platform@@Q$AAA@XZ w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ??0OutOfBoundsException@Platform@@Q$AAA@XZ w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ??0OutOfMemoryException@Platform@@Q$AAA@XZ w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ??BType@Platform@@SA?AVTypeName@Interop@Xaml@UI@Windows@@P$AAV01@@Z w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?AlignedFree@Heap@Details@Platform@@SAXPAX@Z w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?Allocate@Heap@Details@Platform@@SAPAXII@Z w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?AllocateException@Heap@Details@Platform@@SAPAXII@Z w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?CreateException@Exception@Platform@@SAP$AAV12@H@Z w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?CreateValue@Details@Platform@@YGP$AAVObject@2@W4TypeCode@2@PBX@Z w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?EventSourceAdd@Details@Platform@@YG?AVEventRegistrationToken@Foundation@Windows@@PAPAXPAUEventLock@12@P$AAVDelegate@2@@Z w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?EventSourceGetTargetArray@Details@Platform@@YGPAXPAXPAUEventLock@12@@Z w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?EventSourceGetTargetArrayEvent@Details@Platform@@YGPAXPAXIPBXPA_J@Z w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?EventSourceGetTargetArraySize@Details@Platform@@YGIPAX@Z w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?EventSourceInitialize@Details@Platform@@YGXPAPAX@Z w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?EventSourceRemove@Details@Platform@@YGXPAPAXPAUEventLock@12@VEventRegistrationToken@Foundation@Windows@@@Z w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?EventSourceUninitialize@Details@Platform@@YGXPAPAX@Z w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?Free@Heap@Details@Platform@@SAXPAX@Z w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?GetActivationFactory@Details@Platform@@YGJPAVModuleBase@1WRL@Microsoft@@PAUHSTRING__@@PAPAUIActivationFactory@@@Z w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?GetActivationFactoryByPCWSTR@@YGJPAXAAVGuid@Platform@@PAPAX@Z w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?GetCmdArguments@Details@Platform@@YAPAPA_WPAH@Z w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?GetIBoxArrayVtable@Details@Platform@@YGPAXPAX@Z w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?GetIBoxVtable@Details@Platform@@YGPAXPAX@Z w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?GetIidsFn@@YGJHPAKPBU__s_GUID@@PAPAVGuid@Platform@@@Z w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?GetObjectContext@Details@Platform@@YGPAUIUnknown@@XZ w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?GetProxyImpl@Details@Platform@@YGJPAUIUnknown@@ABU_GUID@@0PAPAU3@@Z w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?GetType@Object@Platform@@Q$AAAP$AAVType@2@XZ w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?GetTypeCode@Type@Platform@@SA?AW4TypeCode@2@P$AAV12@@Z w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?GetWeakReference@Details@Platform@@YGPAU__abi_IUnknown@@Q$ADVObject@2@@Z w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?InitializeData@Details@Platform@@YAJH@Z w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?ReCreateException@Exception@Platform@@SAP$AAV12@H@Z w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?ReleaseInContextImpl@Details@Platform@@YGJPAUIUnknown@@0@Z w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?ReleaseTarget@ControlBlock@Details@Platform@@AAEXXZ w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?ResolveWeakReference@Details@Platform@@YGP$AAVObject@2@ABU_GUID@@PAPAU__abi_IUnknown@@@Z w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?TerminateModule@Details@Platform@@YG_NPAVModuleBase@1WRL@Microsoft@@@Z w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?UninitializeData@Details@Platform@@YAXH@Z w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?__abi_ObjectToString@__abi_details@@YGP$AAVString@Platform@@P$AAVObject@3@_N@Z w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?__abi_WinRTraiseAccessDeniedException@@YGXXZ w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?__abi_WinRTraiseCOMException@@YGXJ@Z w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?__abi_WinRTraiseChangedStateException@@YGXXZ w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?__abi_WinRTraiseClassNotRegisteredException@@YGXXZ w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?__abi_WinRTraiseDisconnectedException@@YGXXZ w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?__abi_WinRTraiseFailureException@@YGXXZ w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?__abi_WinRTraiseInvalidArgumentException@@YGXXZ w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?__abi_WinRTraiseInvalidCastException@@YGXXZ w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?__abi_WinRTraiseNotImplementedException@@YGXXZ w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?__abi_WinRTraiseNullReferenceException@@YGXXZ w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?__abi_WinRTraiseObjectDisposedException@@YGXXZ w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?__abi_WinRTraiseOperationCanceledException@@YGXXZ w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?__abi_WinRTraiseOutOfBoundsException@@YGXXZ w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?__abi_WinRTraiseOutOfMemoryException@@YGXXZ w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?__abi_WinRTraiseWrongThreadException@@YGXXZ w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?__abi_cast_Object_to_String@__abi_details@@YGP$AAVString@Platform@@_NP$AAVObject@3@@Z w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?__abi_cast_String_to_Object@__abi_details@@YGP$AAVObject@Platform@@P$AAVString@3@@Z w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?__abi_make_type_id@@YGP$AAVType@Platform@@ABU__abi_type_descriptor@@@Z w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?__abi_translateCurrentException@@YGJ_N@Z w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?get@Message@Exception@Platform@@Q$AAAP$AAVString@3@XZ w vccorlib120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?_Syserror_map@std@@YAPBDH@Z w msvcp120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?_Winerror_map@std@@YAPBDH@Z w msvcp120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?_Xbad_alloc@std@@YAXXZ w msvcp120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?_Xbad_function_call@std@@YAXXZ w msvcp120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z w msvcp120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z w msvcp120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ??0critical_section@Concurrency@@QAE@XZ w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ??0event@Concurrency@@QAE@XZ w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ??0exception@std@@QAE@ABQBD@Z w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ??0exception@std@@QAE@ABQBDH@Z w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ??0exception@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ??0invalid_operation@Concurrency@@QAE@PBD@Z w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ??0scoped_lock@critical_section@Concurrency@@QAE@AAV12@@Z w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ??0task_canceled@Concurrency@@QAE@XZ w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ??1critical_section@Concurrency@@QAE@XZ w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ??1event@Concurrency@@QAE@XZ w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ??1exception@std@@UAE@XZ w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ??1scoped_lock@critical_section@Concurrency@@QAE@XZ w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ??1type_info@@UAE@XZ w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ??2@YAPAXI@Z w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ??3@YAXPAX@Z w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?Alloc@Concurrency@@YAPAXI@Z w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?Free@Concurrency@@YAXPAX@Z w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?GetCurrentThreadId@platform@details@Concurrency@@YAJXZ w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?_Cancel@_TaskCollection@details@Concurrency@@QAEXXZ w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?_GetCurrentInlineDepth@_StackGuard@details@Concurrency@@CAAAIXZ w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?_NewCollection@_AsyncTaskCollection@details@Concurrency@@SAPAV123@PAV_CancellationTokenState@23@@Z w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?_ReportUnobservedException@details@Concurrency@@YAXXZ w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?_RunAndWait@_TaskCollection@details@Concurrency@@QAG?AW4_TaskCollectionStatus@23@PAV_UnrealizedChore@23@@Z w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?_Schedule@_TaskCollection@details@Concurrency@@QAEXPAV_UnrealizedChore@23@@Z w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?_ScheduleTask@_CurrentScheduler@details@Concurrency@@SAXP6AXPAX@Z0@Z w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?__ExceptionPtrCopy@@YAXPAXPBX@Z w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?__ExceptionPtrCreate@@YAXPAX@Z w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?__ExceptionPtrCurrentException@@YAXPAX@Z w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?__ExceptionPtrDestroy@@YAXPAX@Z w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?__ExceptionPtrRethrow@@YAXPBX@Z w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?set@event@Concurrency@@QAEXXZ w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?terminate@@YAXXZ w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?wait@event@Concurrency@@QAEII@Z w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API ?what@exception@std@@UBEPBDXZ w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API _CxxThrowException w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API _XcptFilter w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API __CppXcptFilter w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API __CxxFrameHandler3 w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API __clean_type_info_names_internal w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API __dllonexit w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API __getmainargs w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API __setusermatherr w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API _acmdln w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API _amsg_exit w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API _calloc_crt w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API _cexit w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API _commode w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API _configthreadlocale w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API _controlfp_s w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API _except_handler4_common w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API _exit w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API _exit_app w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API _fmode w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API _initterm w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API _initterm_e w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API _invoke_watson w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API _lock w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API _malloc_crt w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API _onexit w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API _purecall w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API _unlock w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API free w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API malloc w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API memcpy w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API memmove w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API memset w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API wcslen w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
◦Interfejs API wcsrchr w msvcr120_app.dll nie jest obsługiwany dla tego typu aplikacji. App4.exe wywołuje ten interfejs API.
```

I'm stuck. I don't know what I did wrong. I use 'Release' configuration . I did't do any changes to project. When I tried WACK against VisualBasic app, it didn't complain. Does anyone bumped into the same problem? Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-windows_update/kb2976978-makes-wack-fail/a78e8109-cc4a-4f72-bab9-0c34c7acfd1b?rtAction=1419119637635

Apparently Windows Update 2976978 causes this problem.